# Seagate HDD spins up - Not understanding why (WD does not)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, nas, hdparm

I have built a NAS with TrueNAS at my home. I access the data around once every week (twice, as I will run a ZFS scrub once per week), hence I prefer to spin-down the disks when I do not access the data on the pool.

My setup is:

- Odroid H3
- WD Red Plus WD40EFPX
- Seagate IronWolf ST4000VN006
- Mirrored data pool across both disks

I used this script, following its documentation to spin down the disks: https://github.com/ngandrass/truenas-spindown-timer

It works perfectly for the WD disk, which stays spun down until I access the data at any time.

However, the Seagate drive gets spun up at random times. Maybe related to some process running in TrueNAS to check something in the disk.

After performing some tests, I noticed that I can spindown the WD perfectly with hdparm, seeing afterwards that it was successfully stopped
. The same behaviour applies for the WD and for the Seagate disk.

```
hdparm -C /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 drive state is:  standby
```

However, the Seagate will spin up randomly after some minutes. I also noticed that if I set the Seagate drive to sleep mode (`hdparm -Y`) instead of standby (`hdparm -y`), running `hdparm -C` will spin up the disk, while this behaviour does not happen with the WD Red Plus.

Any ideas on to handle this to get both disks spun down for longer periods of time?
Thank you

Comment: Did you [configure the disk standby settings](https://github.com/ngandrass/truenas-spindown-timer?tab=readme-ov-file#configure-disk-standby-settings) for each disk?